# How to properly calculate ETA in ProgressBar when (re)starting at a given position?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony-console

I'm using a `ProgressBar` for my console command, and allow the command to restart at some point in the middle of the processing:

```php
$itemCount = 1_000_000;
$startItem = 150_000;

$progressBar = new ProgressBar($output, $itemCount);
$progressBar->setFormat(
    $progressBar->getFormatDefinition(ProgressBar::FORMAT_DEBUG)
);

$progressBar->start();

if ($startItem !== 0) {
    // unfortunately taken into account in ETA calculation
    $progressBar->advance($startItem);
}

for ($i = $startItem; $i < $itemCount; $i++) {
    usleep(50_000);
    $progressBar->advance();
}
```

The issue is, even though the command processes only ~20 items per second, the ETA is calculated just as if `$startItem` items had been processed right at the beginning of the processing:

```
150038/1000000 [====>-----------------------]  15% 2 secs/13 secs 20.0 MiB
```

I'm expecting the ETA to be ~12 hours here, not 13 secs.

**How can I fix this?** Can I somehow give the starting position of the progress bar *before* starting it, so that the ETA is properly calculated?

Comment: I can confirm this. Might be best to post an issue on the [Symfony Repo](https://github.com/symfony/symfony).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by the `ProgressBar` helper.

The estimated time is calculated by the `ProgressBar#getEstimated()` method, which is very simple:

```
public function getEstimated(): float
{
    if (!$this->step) {
         return 0;
    }

    return round((time() - $this->startTime) / $this->step * $this->max);
}
```

This only takes into account the amount of time since the progress bar has been started (which is set when one calls `ProgressBar#start()`, or on the constructor otherwise), and the total amount of "steps" it's taken so far.

There is no distinction between "real" steps, and "fake" steps. Even if one were to modify  `ProgresBar#step` before calling `start()` (e.g. on the constructor), the result would be the same, since the calculation for estimated time would work exactly the same way.

The class is marked `final`, which I think it's unfortunate for a helper class, so you cannot simply extend it and add your logic (e.g. with an additional `int $resumedAt` property that one could use when calculating the estimated remaining time).

If you really, really need this, I'd simply make a copy of the class in your project and add the necessary logic there.

As a simple proof of concept, I'd copied `ProgressBar` into `App\ProgressBar`, and added this:

```
private int $resumedSteps = 0;

public function resume(int $max = null, int $step = 0): void
{

    $this->startTime = time();
    $this->resumedStep = $step;
    $this->step = $step;

    if (null !== $max) {
        $this->setMaxSteps($max);
    }

    $this->setProgress($step);

    $this->display();
}

public function getEstimated(): float
{
   if ($this->step === 0 || $this->step === $this->resumedStep) {
      return 0;
   }

   return round((time() - $this->startTime) / ($this->step - $this->resumedStep) * $this->max);
}

public function getRemaining(): float
{
   if ($this->step === 0 || $this->step === $this->resumedStep) {
     return 0;
   }

   return round((time() - $this->startTime) / ($this->step - $this->resumedStep) * ($this->max - $this->step));
}
```

One would simply use this as:

```
$itemCount = 1_000_000;

$progressBar = new App\ProgressBar($output, $itemCount);
$progressBar->setFormat(
    $progressBar->getFormatDefinition(ProgressBar::FORMAT_DEBUG)
);

$startItem > 0 ? $progressBar->resume($startItem) : $progressBar->start();
```

Comment: I've been playing around with this and it needs an additional property like `$resumedAt` as you mentioned. IMO it defiantly needs this support added.

Comment: If I can make time later this week, I'll submit a PR to symfony.

Comment: Nice one. Almost the same with what i experimented with..

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. Looking forward to your Symfony PR! Could you please post a link here if you proceed?

Comment: Finally, found the time today, @BenMorel. Let's see if it flies: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/46242